# O que são e para que servem os arquivos .js.map?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Baixei a versão mais recente do Boostrap (4.3.1 na data de hoje).
e reparei que na pasta js, vieram vários arquivos com o final .map

```
js/bootstrap.bundle.js
js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map
js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
js/bootstrap.js
js/bootstrap.js.map
js/bootstrap.min.js
js/bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Para que servem esses arquivos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do pouco que sei na verdade são os `.map` são *SourceMaps* (mapa da fonte). Imagina que vc tem um ambiente de desenvolvimento onde trabalha em arquivos editáveis, que por sua vez na hora da compilação geram arquivos minificados. Debuggar ou dar manutenção em um arquivo minificado é muito ruim e pouco produtivo, então usando um SourceMap vc "linka" as duas versões do seu .JS não minificado => minificado, ou .CSS (compiladores de CSS tb geram arquivos .map). O Gulp ou Ruby por exemplo quando compilam de SCSS para CSS também geram um .map que é o link entre a versão .scss não compilada e a versão .css depois da compilação.

> **O que são Source Maps?**
>   Um mapa de origem é um formato de mapeamento baseado em JSOn que cria uma relação entre um arquivo minificado e suas origens. Ao desenvolver para produção, além de minificar e combinar arquivos JavaScript, você gera um mapa de origem que detém informações sobre seus arquivos originais. ... O arquivo de mapa de origem é um arquivo JSON que define um mapeamento entre cada declaração de CSS gerada e a linha correspondente no arquivo de origem

*Fonte:* https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-preprocessors?hl=pt-br

Inclusive, é por isso que quando se trabalha com *Frameworks* como o Bootstrap é importante vc seguir a organização das pastas e arquivos conforme a documentação, para na compilação os caminhos não falharem e serem salvos e encontrados nos lugares corretos.

Aqui tem um artigo em português que pode te interessar https://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/02/21/sourcemaps-debugando-js-e-css-minificados/